# Максимальный размер массива C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Linux x86 компилятор g++. Не получается создать массив с кол-вом `int` элементов, пробовал даже `int` заменять на `double` все ровно пишет `size of array is too large`, как создать массив с максимальным кол-вом элементов? Или какой тогда максимальный размер массива? Пробовал `unsigned int` все ровно та же ошибка.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  cout << "RAND_MAX: " << RAND_MAX << endl;
  cout << "RAND_NUM: " << RAND_NUM << endl;

  int a[2147483646];
  for (int i = 0; i < 2147483646; i++){
    a[i] = rand();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Все конечно зависит от компилятора. Ну и от оперативной памяти. Ну а максимальная вложенность `[][][]` и т.д. равна 255.

Comment: @And пробовал больше 3-х вложенностей - ошибка

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Максимальный размер массива зависит от количества доступной памяти.

Если создаёте массив на стеке (как в коде из вопроса), то память ограничена размером стека (дефолтный размер стека в линуксе можно посмотреть командой `ulimit -s`, его так же можно увеличить через настройки компилятора). Допустим, у вас дефолтный размер стека равен 10 Мб, тогда максимальный размер массива `int32` получается `10*1024*1024 / 4 = 2621440` элементов. Но весь стек заюзать не получится, т.к. он нужен ещё и для хранения локальных переменных и параметров функций.

Если создавать массив в динамической памяти (через `malloc`), то для 32-х битного приложения доступно максимум 2 Гб оперативки (но реально до 1,5 Гб можно успешно выделить). Тогда расчёты будут такими: `2*1024*1024*1024 / 4 = 536870912` элементов.

А теперь сравните полученные цифры с вашими.

Comment: @user1  8 388 608 / sizeof(int) = 2097152 элементов. Зачем вы вообще создаете их на стеке? Стек не резиновый и полезно ограничиться 4кб. Создавайте массив в куче. Тогда максимальный размер будет определяться величиной наибольшего доступного непрерывного блока памяти и варьироваться в зависимости от фрагментации памяти.

Comment: Извините не до конца понял ответ, написал комментарий, а потом прочитал еще раз ответ, разобрался в своей ошибке и удалил комментарий(за ненадобностью).

Comment: Все верно, динамический размер массива, равен доступной оперативной памяти.